# Plotting multiple variables from same data frame in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set which could be defined thus:

```
Week <- c("2015_52", "2016_01", "2016_02", "2016_03", "2016_04")
y1 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
y2 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
y3 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(Week, y1, y2, y3)
```

I want to plot all three of the y's over time on the same ggplot (with manual colors and linetype for each one), but I'm new to ggplot and have not had to do this before. Trying to emulate answers to similar questions on StackOverflow is delivering errors.

For instance...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

...as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889526/plotting-multiple-variables-in-ggplot) gives the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found`.

But trying as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921842/plotting-multiple-time-series-on-the-same-plot-using-ggplot)...

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(x = Week, y = y1, 
                color = "black", linetype = "solid")) + 
  geom_line(data = df, 
            aes(x = Week, y = y2, 
                color = "red", linetype = "solid")) +
  geom_line(data = df,
            aes(x = Week, y = y3, 
                color = "orange", linetype = "dashed"))
```

...gives three instances of the error `geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group
aesthetic?`. Can I get some assistance, please?

Comment: The only way to do this right is to convert the data from wide format (as you have defined it) to long format with something like the `reshape2` package. Painful to learn, but once you do you will never look back.

Comment: Here is a good answer to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r/19039094#19039094

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that one when searching.

Comment: Any chance you could mark this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is what you really want I think:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(123)
Week <- c("2015_52", "2016_01", "2016_02", "2016_03", "2016_04")
y1 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
y2 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
y3 <- runif(5, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(Week, y1, y2, y3)

mdf <- melt(df,id.vars="Week")

ggplot(mdf, aes( x=Week, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable )) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("y1"="black","y2"="red","y3"="orange")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("y1"="solid","y2"="solid","y3"="dashed"))
```

Note that leaving the `group=variable` out will cause the following dreaded message:

> ```
> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group
> aesthetic?
> ```

yielding:

[image]

Comment: Aha! It was the string-type Week values which were causing me to get the "Each group consists of only one observation" error. Much thanks.

Comment: np. Would appreciate a correct check of course :)

Comment: Not happy with the week labels yet. Am figuring this out.

Comment: Ok, there we go. Finally groking the `group` aes.